# How to split a string when first letter is found in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

If i have:

```
var x = "123442234535asd";
```

What regular expression would I have to use on `x.split(regex);` to get "asd"?

PS: `x` would always have a random string of numbers first and a string of letters after.

Comment: And why not just remove the numbers, `x.replace(/\d/g,'');`

Comment: Couldn't you just match `[a-zA-Z]+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply remove the digits:

```
var x = "123442234535asd";
x = x.replace(/\d+/, "");
console.log(x);
```

---

**output:**

```
asd
```

### [CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/VLZMey)

If you really need to split the string you can use:

```
var x = "123442234535asd";
x= x.split(/\d+/);
```

Comment: Wait, is the `+` after the digit matching shortcut needed there? I was thinking global `g` was what was needed, but it turns out here that either works.

Comment: @VítorMartins, se a minha resposta te ajudou, por favor considera aceitá-la como a resposta correta, obrigado !

Comment: @Pedro Lobito , desculpa ainda não podia aceitar tinham que passar uns minutos, já aceitei, obrigado ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
x.split(/[0-9]+/);
```

the last element in the array would be 'asd'

Comment: yeah my bad, forgot about that...:)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split and only keep non-empty elements in the array that you get, use [`.filter(Boolean)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) after splitting:

```js
var x = "123442234535asd";
alert(x.split(/[0-9]/g).filter(Boolean));
```